# Creating a list of pairs using comprehensions out of 1 list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

This is my list : `num_list = [82 , 41 , 147 , 563 , 91]`

Create a new list of value pairs so that the first element of each pair remains the same and the second element is a logical value with a `True` value if the value is even otherwise the `False` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping it simple:

```
[(num, (num % 2) == 0) for num in num_list]
```

The idea behind this expresion is to check if your number can be divided (exactly) by 2 (`num % 2`). If that's the case, the reminder is 0 (`== 0`).

---

If you want to use a bit shorter condition:

```
[(num, not (num % 2)) for num in num_list]
```

This is the same, the only difference is that we're using the fact that 0 is `False`, so `not 0` is always `True`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was trying for a long time because it seemed strange to me that they should be pairs and the second value should be boolean, out of a list with intigers.